# How to define Q matrix (covariance matrix for process noise) in EKF

Tags: discrete-signals, kalman-filters

I am implementing an Extended Kalman Filter (EKF). I have developed the model for my system and I know must find the Q matrix. I have searched all over the web and noone explains how to define this matrix. I just find that is it is only the covariance matrix for process noise which I already know.

So my question is if there is like a general mathematical way to define the matrix or it has to be done experimentally maybe like starting with some random values and then try to tune them?

In either solution how can it be done?

Comment: If you can't evaluate the variance covariance of your state (by looking at some historic data?) maybe you should try and guess it yourself and hand tune it yourself like you said. Note that I'm not 100% sure of what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

[Anderson and Moore's *Optimal Filtering*](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ejohn/papers/BOOK/B02.PDF) defines the discrete-time system to be Kalman filtered on page 13  in (2.1) and (2.2) as:

\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= F_k x_k + G_k w_k \tag{2.1}\\
z_k &= y_k + v_k = H'_k x_k + v_k \tag{2.2}
\end{align}

Then, on page 15, they define $Q_k$ using
$$
E[w_kw'_l ] = Q_k \delta_{kl} \tag{2.7}
$$

For the **extended** Kalman filter, the signal model changes, in chapter 8 to:
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= f_k(x_k) + g_k(x_k) w_k \tag{1.1}\\
z_k &= y_k + v_k = h_k(x_k) + v_k \tag{1.2}
\end{align}
but the definition of $Q_k$ doesn't change
(sic: that's the way they're numbered in the PDF).

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah but again the noise $w_{k}$ should be known somehow, shouldnt't it?

Comment: @useeeeer132 Usually only know or guess the variance and assume whiteness, so it's just one number.